# Issue with date in SOLR with sometimes added milliseconds

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using solr 7-4 and I get a

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-03-15T20:02:52.335Z' could not be parsed at index 19

when I try to parse a date that is stored in the index with

```
LocalDate.parse(documentModifDateAsString,SOLR_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

with `SOLR_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");` (only up to seconds not up to millis)

I understand the exception, but I don't know how such a date could appear since Solr should store all dates with the pattern [`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/working-with-dates.html).

My date field is named `modifiedDate_dt` and the `managed-schema.xml` shows

```
<dynamicField name="*_dt" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

How could I force Solr (or whoever) to always store dates only up to seconds ?

So far to mitigate this I have been catching the exception and trying to parse up to millis :

```
SOLR_DATE_TIME_FORMAT_UP_TO_MILLIS = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

But I should also parse with `S` and `SS` as well. This looks a bit awkward.

Any help appreciated,

Comment: can you check if you can apply the dateformat as  "datetimeformat="YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'"" and type="date" to your field?

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitBashetti. I would rather not change the name of the field which would occur if I change its type from `_dt` to `_date. Anyway` I've just tried to **parse** with `sss` and it's not possible, since quoting from the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `Up to two letters of 'd', 'H', 'h', 'K', 'k', 'm', and 's' can be specified`. So I doubt 3 small s for the number of second would be allowed in Solr.

Comment: What exactly is throwing that exception and where is that LocalDate parse code coming from? It feels like maybe there is a hidden conversion from Solr's date into string and maybe that's where it gets corrupted. I would also check all the possible date format definitions and make sure they are correct (and - for example - not using MSWord auto-substituted curly quotes....)

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch the date is retrieved from `new Date(f.lastModified())` where f is a regular java.io.File.

Comment: Be aware that Solr will store the actual, verbatim value submitted for the field - so if you're submitting milliseconds, you'll get milliseconds back. And Solr supports millisecond precision for its datetypes: _Solr’s date fields (DatePointField, DateRangeField and the deprecated TrieDateField) represent "dates" as a point in time with millisecond precision._

Comment: @MatsLindh What I see is, with the same indexer (stored as show in the comment above), for some documents I get seconds and for some other I get in addition millis.  However catching the exception as shown above seems to work.